# Speeding up OSMnx travel time polygon calculation

Tags: python, networkx, geopandas, osmnx

I have a list of 500 locations in the Netherlands, each with a lat/lon coordinate. I want to calculate a travel time polygon for each location based on a 15-minute travel time. I wrote a code using osmnx, networkx, and GeoPandas libraries, which works, but the process is very slow as I have to download a bounding box of 25*25 km for each location and convert it to a multidigraph.

I am looking for suggestions on how to optimize my code for efficiency. Is there a way to avoid downloading the bounding box for each location, or a better approach to calculate the travel time polygons? I am open to any suggestions or alternative libraries that can help me achieve my goal.

I attempted to improve the code's performance by dividing the entire region into smaller pieces and downloading and storing each bounding box separately as ".graphml" files. However, when I attempted to aggregate these files into a single multidigraph for calculating travel times, the resulting file size was approximately 2GB, and this appears to be causing issues. I am seeking advice on an alternative approach to efficiently generate the travel time polygons for all 500 locations.

The basic code I am using is as follow:

```
# Select correct row from the dataset
start = infra_dataframe[i-1:i]

# Set CRS
start.crs = "EPSG:4326"

# Set distance value in seconds
distance_value = 900 # 900 seconds = 15 minutes

# Create buffer around geometry point (7855 represents CRS in meters) and set back to correct CRS
buffer_value = distance_value*25 # multiply by 25 to ensure the buffer area is large enough
buffer_home = start.to_crs(epsg=7855).buffer(buffer_value).to_crs(epsg=4326)

# Get a bounding box of the buffer
bounds = buffer_home.bounds.loc[i-1]

# Get road information and add travel times for surrounding area
# Define a custom filter to select roads of interest
cf = '["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|trunk|trunk_link|primary|primary_link|secondary|secondary_link|tertiary|tertiary_link|residential|unclassified|living_street|service"]'

# Get a graph of the road network within the bounding box
region = ox.graph_from_bbox(bounds['maxy'], bounds['miny'], bounds['minx'], bounds['maxx'], network_type='drive', custom_filter=cf)

# Add travel times and speed to the edges of the graph
G = ox.add_edge_speeds(region)
G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(region)

# Find the center node of the graph that is closest to the starting point
center_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, start['infra.lon'].iloc[0], start['infra.lat'].iloc[0])

# Compute the shortest path lengths from the center node to all other nodes in the graph
distances = nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=center_node, weight="travel_time")

# Select the nodes that are reachable within the set time limit
drivable_nodes = {node: dist for node, dist in distances.items() if dist < distance_value}

# Create a subgraph that includes only the reachable nodes
G_reachable = G.subgraph(drivable_nodes.keys())

# Convert the subgraph to GeoDataFrames containing nodes and edges
gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_reachable)

# Use custom built function create_polygon to turn nodes into a polygon
reachable_polygon = create_polygon(gdf_nodes)

# Put polygon in a geodataframe
gdf_reachable = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[reachable_polygon])
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added the basis code to my initial question to clarify the issue. Please let me know if anything else is unclear.